# Outlook 2010 extensibility, which API to choose?

Tags: c#, .net, api, outlook, outlook-2010

I would like to add some features to the Outlook 2010 application. 
Those features will include:

- adding a button to the ribbon,
- manipulating the calendar,
- display Windows Form after the ribbon button is pressed.

I managed to find out that there are several ways to interfere with Outlook programmatically. They are: the object model, PIA, MAPI, and auxiliary APIs. [(Source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg608200.aspx)

Which approach would you recommend to achieve the above requirements? I would like to use C#. Any tip on Outlook development is very welcome.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to write an add-in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_SampleAddin. How the add-in interacts with Outlook rather depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

[VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430) is probably the easiest way to do that, since it's got designer support in Visual Studio for working with the ribbon.

You can get started by using Create New Project in VS, and expanding the "Office" menu.

Comment: What about the other package? AddIn Express or something like that? Is it long gone and forgotten or still a strong alternative?